# Stripe Connect - Error Refunding Application Fee?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

In my app I am creating a charge, like so:

```
$appFee = 100;
$depositCharge = 2000;

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxx');

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
     "amount" => (int) $depositCharge,
     "currency" => "usd",
     "capture" => "true",
     "destination" => $providerID,
     "application_fee" => (int) $appFee,
     "customer" => $customerID
));
```

Later on, I am trying to process a refund with the API, and also refund the application fee (so my connected account doesn't eat the fee)

```
$re = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
     "charge" => $chargeID,
     "refund_application_fee" => "true"
));
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Attempting to refund_application_fee on charge ch_xxxxxx, but it has no application fee. To refund the application fee on the associated transfer, set reverse_transfer=true."
  }
}
```

If I leave out the 'refund_application_fee' parameter, it works fine. Why is this parameter causing an error?

Comment: Have you asked Stripe? Not sure we can help you with why it's throwing this particular error

Comment: why don't you just do what its telling you to do and set `reverse_transfer = true` ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to provide the Stripe Account Id of the Connected account which is I think *$providerID* in your case while creating the Refund.

I have not tested your case, but I was also getting same issue that when I set *refund_application_fee* the Refund gives error and leaving it out works fine.

After that I Provided Stripe Account Id of the Connected account against which Charge was being created and Refund was successful with *refund_application_fee* set to true.